# Grails, where can methods be defined?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am wondering where methods can be defined and used in groovy/grails.

Specifically in the bootstrap init, I would like to do something like this:

```
def init = {
  def util() {
    return 'so helpful!'
  }

  def someObj = new someObj(phrase: util()).save()
}
```

Is this possible, or does `util` need to be defined outside of init?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think defining named function within a function is not allowed. You can use a closure instead.

```
def init = {

   def util = {->
       "hello"
   }
   def someObj = new someObj(phrase: util()).save()
}
```

Comment: There's no harm in creating a function outside of `init` either.

Comment: One advantage of defining it as a closure inside init is that it will have access to the variable defined in init.